# changing URL on click AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am trying to add a parameter to the current url on click on a div so that i dont loose other paraments and also get some new paraments

```
 <div class='tabes_09o12rt' onclick="window.location.search += '&sort=FOO';">
 <div class='tabes_09o12rt' onclick="window.location.search += '&sort=BAR';">
```

this is working fine but when i click on first div it adds the paramenter FOO to the url and when i click the div 2 it adds the paramenter BAR with the same neme, what i want is that if the paramenter is already added with that name then change it with new name and if not added then add, and on double click remve that paramenter. can we do that ???

Comment: Post up your js related to the question also.

Comment: You can add function onclick and check manually for the paramater is already exist in URL. If still does not work, Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the URL and then use the [URLSearchParams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to manipulate it instead of blindly appending.

```js
const url = new URL(location);
console.log("Original", url.toString());
url.searchParams.set("sort", "foo")
console.log("Foo", url.toString());
url.searchParams.set("sort", "bar")
console.log("Bar", url.toString());
// location = url;
```

Comment: i dont know how can i implement this into function ??

Comment: The same way as anything else. There's nothing here that makes turning it into a function weird.

Comment: on click of the div how to add the parameters to url and refresh it ?? i have tried it adds tha paremeter into console but dosent refreshes with new URL

Comment: @Amani — You still have to assign the result to the location object. I commented that line out in the demo because it wouldn't make sense in a live demo on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Of course we can do that. Just store the original string and retrieve it in a function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var origin = window.location.search;
    function sort(method) {
       window.location.search = origin + '&sort=' + method;
    }
</script>

<div onClick="sort(foo)">Sort using foo</div>
<div onClick="sort(bar)">Sort using bar</div>
```

Comment: There is no practical difference between that and the code in the question. Assigning a new value to `location.search` will cause the browser to navigate. The question is about when the page loads with search parameters in the URL at the start.